# Возможна ли сортировка динамического двухмерного массива с помощью qsort?

Tags: c, сортировка, динамические-массивы, qsort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int sort_mas(const int *i, const *j){
    return *i - *j; 
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int n=4; 
    int b=5; 

    int **mat=malloc(n*sizeof(int*)); 
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    mat[i]=malloc(b*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
    mat[i][j]=rand() %40; 
    printf("%3d",mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    }

    printf("\n"); 

    qsort(mat,n*b,sizeof(int),(int(*)(const void * , const void * ))sort_mas);         
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int  j=0;j<b;j++)
        printf("%3d",mat[i][j]); 
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

компилятор  выдает  Segmentation fault (core dumped).
Результат  должен  быть таким например, исходный - {{3,5,8},{2,1,7},{4,6,9}} должно получиться {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}

Comment: Объясните, как вы видите отсортированный массив? Например, исходный - `{{3,5,8},{2,1,7},{4,6,9}}` - что должно получиться?

Comment: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}

Comment: А. впрочем, в любом случае **такого** массива, как у вас - нет. Потому что `qsort` сортирует *непрерывную* последовательность элементов, а она у вас совсем не является таковой...

Comment: А можете    пожалуйста подсказать  ,как  отсортировать  этот массив используя  иной  метод  сортировки,что  бы получить  такой  результат  .

Comment: Если памяти очень много - скопировать в один одномерный массив, отсортировать, скопировать назад. Если много - работать вручную, реализуя какой-то из алгоритмов, просто написав функцию обращения к `k`-му элементу дыумерного массива...

Comment: `const *j` - это еще что такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Почему вдруг цикл инициализации массива `mat` идет до `b`, а не до `n`???

  ```
  for(int i=0;i<b;i++)            // ???
    mat[i]=malloc(b*sizeof(int));
  ```
- Функция сравнения должна принимать параметры типа `const void *`, а не `const int *`

  ```
  int sort_mas(const void *p1, const void *p2)
  {
    int i = *(const int *) p1, j = *(const int *) p2;
    return (i > j) - (i < j); 
  }
  ```
- Для использования `qsort` надо было с самого начала выделять память для элементов массива как один непрерывный блок

  ```
  int **mat = malloc(n * sizeof *mat); 
  mat[0] = malloc(n * b * sizeof *mat[0]); 

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    mat[i] = mat[0] + i * b;
  ```

  Вызов `qsort` при этом будет выглядеть так

  ```
  qsort(*mat, n * b, sizeof **mat, sort_mas);
  ```
- Память следует не забывать освобождать
- Для использования функции `time` необходимо включить `<time.h>`

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72198d3c9943be50